# Dealing with memory leaks and changing array size

Tags: c++

I am making a templated class holding a variable named `array`, and the user is allowed to change the size of this array. I am wondering how to deal with memory leaks?

```
templated <class T>
class MyClass{
    long *array;
    MyClass(long min, long max);
    void Add(long n);
}

MyClass<T>::MyClass(long min, long max){
    array= new long[min];
}
void  MyClass<T>::Add(long n){
    delete [] array;
    array = new long[n];
}
```

(Yes, I know a vector would be better, but I must use arrays.)

Does this effectively change the size of the array to `n` and account for memory leaks?

Comment: To deal with memory leaks, first of all add a destructor.

Comment: Where are you expecting memory leak? Of course you should define a destructor...

Comment: What, exactly, is the template parameter for?

Comment: You need to change all the `long`s to `T`s. And the user was probably not expecting to lose all the data in the old array. You should probably also store the current size of the array in order to access it properly.

Comment: Meant to say, does simply adding "delete [] array;" deal with basic memory leaks?

Comment: Yes is should! Also do you really want to have your constructor private?

Comment: Okay thanks.  Also Thanks ooga for that, will fix and good idea with storing current size.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a class that dynamically allocates memory, you need a destructor to deallocate it. In your case, your MyClass destructor needs to also `delete[] array;`